# Can I access Flash data before they are rendered by the browser?

Tags: c++, flash, open-source, browser, streaming

Is it possible to read numbers and names from a Flash page before they are rendered by the browser ? The webpage is changing dynamically and I would like to capture the data every about 60 minutes.

I have no access to the Flash website but I might be able to modify an open source browser if this would help. OS is Win 7 and I can speak a little C++.

Answer (score 0):

The data is chnaging dynamically means that there is some page at backend serving to the flash page. Use a sniffer (such as [ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)) to know the serving page. Then you can call the page directly.

Another solution might be create a screenshot of browser and then pass this to a OCR

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simple_ocr.aspx